# How do I delete this Void Pointer?

Tags: c++, memory-management, void-pointers

```
#define ALIGNBUF(Length) Length % ALIGNSIZE ? \
              Length + ALIGNSIZE - (Length % ALIGNSIZE) : Length 

short NumCols;
long * ColLenArray, * OffsetArray;

ColLenArray = new long(NumCols * sizeof(long));
OffsetArray = new long(NumCols * sizeof(long));

// THIS CODE SHOULD NOT BE NEEDED TO UNDERSTAND THE PROBLEM
// BUT I HAVE INCLUDED IT JUST IN CASE
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
SQLColAttribute(hstmt, ((SQLUSMALLINT) i)+1, SQL_DESC_OCTET_LENGTH, NULL, 0, NULL, &ColLenArray[i]);
    ColLenArray[i] = ALIGNBUF(ColLenArray[i]);
    if (i)
        OffsetArray[i] = OffsetArray[i-1]+ColLenArray[i-1]+ALIGNBUF(sizeof(SQLINTEGER));
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void **DataPtr = new void*[OffsetArray[NumCols - 1] + ColLenArray[NumCols - 1] + ALIGNBUF(sizeof(long))];

delete []DataPtr;
```

Don't think it can be done, have tried every way imaginable.

This code works, as in the program runs, I just can't deallocate the memory. Every time this code is called(not all code included as it isn't relevant) the memory gets bigger. I think that deletion is not happening properly and that the `void *` keeps growing.

I have also changed some of the code above based on recommendations here, but as this code is, the memory keeps growing.

Comment: `ColLenArray = new long(NumCols * sizeof(long));` is this a typo? You're doing `ColLenArray[NumCols - 1]` later on.

Comment: @Luc I dont see the problem? ColLenArray is a pointer.

Comment: A pointer yes, but to a single long. You can only index in a pointer to the element of an array.

Comment: @Luc I also call this code after the pointer is created. SQLColAttribute(hstmt, ((SQLUSMALLINT) i)+1, SQL_DESC_OCTET_LENGTH, NULL, 0, NULL, &ColLenArray[i]);
  ColLenArray[i] = ALIGNBUF(ColLenArray[i]);

Comment: @PoiXen `&ColLenArray[i]` is an rvalue through which you can't modify `ColLenArray` and the `ColLenArray[i] = ALIGNBUF(...);` assignment still doesn't modify `ColLenArray` *and* indexes through it. No matter which way you slice it, you're indexing into a pointer to a single long every time so I hope `i` (and the other offsets) are always 0... This also applies to `OffsetArray`.

Comment: @luc This is true, the result is always 0 . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try avoid mixing `void*` and `new`. In C++ actually, `new` is meant to automatically determine the type of the pointer; then why should not use it. At least you can use `char*`, if you are simply dealing with raw bytes.

Other point is `new void*[SIZE]` allocates `void**`. So you should change the declaration to `void **DataPtr`. Remove typecasting ahead of `new`. You can now `delete[] DataPtr;`.

### Edit:

The code have some problems, the variables should be declared like below:

```
ColLenArray = new long[NumCols * sizeof(long)]; // declare as long[] (not long())
OffsetArray = new long[NumCols * sizeof(long)];
```

when you declare those variables as, `new long()`; it will simply initialize the value and assign a pointer to **single** `long`.

The memory corruption happens because, you are using `ColLenArray[i]`, which is accessing wrong memory. Since you are going to use above variables as arrays, it should be `new long[]`. Then memory corruption will not happen. After usage, you should `delete[]` them.

Comment: @iammilind changing void **DataPtr = (void**)new void**[OffsetArray[NumCols - 1] + ColLenArray[NumCols - 1] + ALIGNBUF(sizeof(SQLINTEGER))]; to void **DataPtr = new void*[OffsetArray[NumCols - 1] + ColLenArray[NumCols - 1] + ALIGNBUF(sizeof(SQLINTEGER))]; doesnt seem to dealloc the memory, checked in the task manager and the memoery keeps going up with every function call.

Comment: I suggested `void** DataPtr = new void*[...];` in my answer. Did you try that ? Also while deallocating, it should be `delete[] DataPtr;`, as you are allocating array.

Answer (score 3):

You can't invoke `delete` on a `void *`.

The solution is to not cast a pointer-to-`void**` (which is what `new void*[...]` will give you) to `void*`.  I don't really know what your code is supposed to be doing, but have you tried changing the type of `DataPtr` to `void **`?

**More generally, avoid `void*` as far as possible in C++.**  There are better solutions.  If you edit your question to describe what you're trying to achieve, then we may be able to help suggest something.

Comment: @user: You should be able to call `delete` (or `delete []` in this case) on a `void **`.

Comment: @Oli:  Smart phrasing "Avoid void" :D +1

Answer (score 0):

You just want a block of memory that you can pass to some database library routines? Allocate thus:

```
char * buffer = new char[ len ];
```

len is the length of the buffer in bytes. To delete, simply do:

```
delete [] buffer;
```

You want a void* to pass to a function?

```
void * DataPtr = static_cast< void* >( buffer );
```

For extra merit points, use boost to manage deletion:

```
boost::scoped_array< char > buffer( new char[ len ] );
```

... then you don't have to worry about deletion. To get the buffer here, you need:

```
void * DataPtr = static_cast< void* >( buffer.get() );
```